# Why am I likely to be getting an error in GDI in a c# screen recording app?

Tags: c#, gdi, screenshot

Im trying to write an app that takes a screen shot every 40ms and saves it to disk, im getting an error in GDI

Anybody know if im being too adventurous trying to save a screen shot as jpeg every 40ms or at a rate of 25 fps?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ScreenRecorder
{
    class Program
    {

    private static System.Timers.Timer screenTimer;

    private static int screenNumber;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        screenTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(40);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        screenTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(screenTimer_Elapsed);

        screenTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.Read();
    }


    static void screenTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the screen
        Image myImage = CaptureScreen();
        myImage.Save(@"C:\stuff\Development\ScreenRecorder\ScreenImages\img" + screenNumber + ".jpg");
        myImage.Dispose();

        screenNumber++;
    }

    private static Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height));
        }
        return target;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: is the error message a secret? =)

Comment: You should write your error to save us from compiling it ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

GDI+ is not reentrant nor multithreadable (what-a-word).  You are probably getting (your secret error) because two different threads are competing for GDI+ resources.

From `System.Timers.Timer` documentation:

> The server-based Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to handle the raised Elapsed event, resulting in more accuracy than Windows timers in raising the event on time.

Use `Forms.Timer` to serialize your capturing to message queue of the form, you'll get much better chance of not breaking it.  You might get what you want - but - use PNG instead of JPG.  It will be more efficient for 'normal' forms.

`Multithreading` `+` `GDI+` `=` `big NO NO`.

Also - you won't get your pictures at regular interval - but you don't have to worry about that since any change what can expected is to occur from the message loop also - so you won't miss a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's going to blow.  The timer's Elapsed method will run on a threadpool thread, regardless whether the previous one has finished.  Your screen capture + bitmap save is bound to take longer than 40 milliseconds.  Sooner or later, probably sooner, two Elapsed handlers are going to run concurrently, using the same screenNumber variable value.  Kaboom on not being able to overwrite a locked file.

You'll need to use a System.Threading.Timer instead.  Start it with a *period* of 0 so the callback only runs once.  After the screenshot, restart the timer again.  Now you can be sure that you'll never get more than one thread running at the same time.

Comment: Good point, but maybe he *is* fast enough?  Also, using Threading timer won't save him from shooting into GDI from main thread and from his 'capture' event.

Comment: @Daniel - I readily assume he's not, full screen captures are big bitmaps.  GDI+ won't be the problem, it can be called from a worker thread.  As long as a bitmap object is only 'touched' by one thread at a time.  Not sure if the encoders can run concurrently, but the point is to not test this.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ScreenRecorder
{
    class Program
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer screenTimer;
        private static int screenNumber;
        private static Mutex m = new Mutex();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            screenTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(40);

            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
            screenTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(screenTimer_Elapsed);
            screenTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.Read();
        }


        static void screenTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(()=>SaveImage());
            t.Start();
        }

        private static void SaveImage()
        {
            m.WaitOne();
            Image myImage = CaptureScreen();
            myImage.Save(@"C:\stuff\Development\ScreenRecorder\ScreenImages\img" + screenNumber + ".png");
            myImage.Dispose();
            screenNumber++;
            m.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        private static Image CaptureScreen()
        {
            Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height));
            }
            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what does  Thread t = new Thread(() => SaveImage()); mean?

Comment: It initialize new thread object, threads are something like processes but they are all work together inside a single process or I can say they are sub processes, ()=>saveimage() is a lambda expression. it simply shows that the function that the thread should run is saveimage()